# detect circular reference in an object

Tags: java

Suppose you have a java object, would it be possible to detect where exists `circular references inside that java object`?

I would like to hear if there is a library to deal with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a lateral answer, but how about using [`net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(...)`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#fromObject%28java.lang.Object%29) which [checks for circular references](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html#objects) and throws an exception if any are found. Also, you can configure the library to handle circular references differently if necessary. You would have to write a getter for those class members that exist in the cyclical relationship, since that is what JSONObject uses to create the JSON.

Comment: Thanks. even I just tried using XStream json, I got this: com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller$CircularReferenceException:  but then I dont know where it the circular reference. Any ideas?

Comment: For this json-lib, you can register a [CycleDetectionStrategy](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/util/CycleDetectionStrategy.html) and get access to the "repeated" object. It might be possible to do something similar with XStream but for some reason the XStream API is not working for me at the moment so I can't check!

Comment: thanks. any idea if i just tried: JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(myModel ); and I got this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException Thanks!

Comment: No, I got this: net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher

Comment: You are missing the library dependencies, which are documented on the [main page](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi, thanks. now I get this problem: net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.ClassCastException: JSON keys must be strings.

Comment: json-lib cannot create a JSON Object (e.g. `{"key":"value"}`) from your Class as one of the keys is not a string, and is probably null. When serializing the Class to JSON, json-lib will create JSON Objects (and JSON Arrays) but it is not valid to have a null key. If you can add your example Java Classes to the question, I may be able to help further. Or you could try creating two simple Classes in a cyclical relationship with just a simple String member, to test this method first. In short, something in one of your Classes cannot be JSON serialized with json-lib

Answer (score 4):

Beware, this is not trivial task, but you already know this, right? ;)

In Java there is implementation of [IdentityHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) that is designed to be uses in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually simple, but can be quite complex to implement.

First off, a lot depends on what type of objects you're dealing with.  If only a small number of object classes, and you "own" the classes and can modify them to add "search yourself" code, then it becomes much easier:

Add an interface to each class and implement the "search yourself" method in each class.  The method receives a list of objects, and returns a return code.  The method compares its own address to each object on the list, returning true (ie, loop found) if one matches.  Then (if no match) it adds its own address to the list and calls, in turn, the "search yourself" method of each object reference it contains.  If any of these calls results in a true return code, that is returned, otherwise false is returned.  (This is a "depth-first, recursive" search.)

If you don't "own" the classes then you must use reflections to implement essentially the above algorithm without modifying the classes.

There are other search algorithms that can be used -- "breadth-first", and various non-recursive versions of depth-first, but they all represent trade-offs of one sort or another of between heap storage, stack storage, and performance.

Comment: (IdentityHashMap would be a good way to implement the list of objects.)

Comment: One can also replace the object list with a bit mask, with a given object's position in the mask being assigned (using a global counter) the first time the object is searched.

Comment: Of course, you can probably best implement the algorithm by adding fields to the objects.  Each object needs a bool, two ints, and a pointer to an object of your "search yourself" interface.  No recursion needed, and no danger of blowing the stack.  Will perform in under aN + bM time, where N is the total number of objects and M is the total number of inter-object pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be simple task to code. Use Java Reflection API to crawl the graph of java objects and collect visited objects. If you visit object that is already in the set that means that there has to be a circuit. To crawl use BFS or DFS algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any library. It's simple breadth-first search alghoritm and reflection API. Of course you can try to find a library implementing this alghoritm.